# Construction of a List of byte[] in a MemoryStream: Wrong number of elements C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a List of byte[], from a List of BitmapImage, by getting their bytes using MemoryStream.

I put an image to let you see the debugger, which tells me that the size of my array is 1,048,576. And that is exactly what I want from my calculations:

[image]

But, now let me show you the result of the Console.WriteLine:

[image]

There are, at the end, 460 arrays of bytes, and none of them actually have the right number of bytes

And later in my code, I get an "out of range" exception

Am I doing this wrong? Why is the debugger giving me the "right" values ("right" because this is what I want) but it seems like they are wrong ?

Comment: 1048576 is 0x100000 which is a nice round number that looks rather unusual for an image size. How do you know that the debugger's result is correct versus the output? Are you sure they are the same images being processed?

Comment: I'm working with a set of images of 512*512px, and I want to store rgba of each pixel in this array so 512*512*4 = 1048576

Comment: PNG is a compressed format. It looks like the sizes output by WriteLine are the size of the compressed images in the memory stream. Not sure why the debugger is showing something different though but just a guess.

Comment: is Jpeg a compressed format too? considering what you told me, I tried with another encoder (JpegBitmapEncoder), and I get an out of range exception earlier than with the PngBitmapEncoder (I mean that the index with which I get the exception is lower than before). Are there encoders who don't compress data?

Comment: I believe BmpBitmapEncoder stores uncompressed.